# Using File.chown() in ruby as root to be owned by user

Tags: ruby, file

I'm looking to simply open and write a new file, then have it owned by another user (while running as root). The file creation works alright but the file still ends up being owned by root. I'm using:

```
doc="text"
uid=Etc.getpwnam("#{$user}").uid

File.open("#{$file}", 'w') {|f| 
            f.write(doc)
            f.chown($uid,$uid)
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Globals! Yikes. [Ruby Style Guide, Add Globals to Kernel](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#misc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only a process with superuser privileges may change the owner of a file. [[RubyDocs]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-i-chown)

Try running ruby with `sudo`.

**EDIT**

Second argument should be group ID. Not user ID.

**EDIT 2**

Turned out to be the globals. My heart has never been happier. Please see comments.

Comment: Sorry! I should have included in the code block the execution, but it is being executed as root.

Comment: I think your second argument needs to be a group ID instead of a user id.

Comment: Answer: Commented in OP, poor use of globals